# Blazegraph Data Loader

Tags: rdf, bulkloader, dataloader, blazegraph

I try to import some triple into the Blazegraph data base, whereas all triple w/o data type get loaded.

But triples having e.g. ^^xsd:date format get not loaded?!

Does anyone know how to deal with that issue?

Examples not being loaded:

```
<http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/oPbZa6d9xntUXB><http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/CREATION_DATE>"2015-08-24"^^xsd:date .
<http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/oPbZa6d9xntUXB><http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/S4_PROP_CLASS>"02"^^xsd:int .
```

Examples being loaded (see line two, the language tag works also properly):

```
<http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/oPbZa6d9xntUXB><http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/IMPORT_ID>"20000" .
<http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/oPbZa6d9xntUXB><http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/OBJECT_TYPE>"S4_DFTRevision"@en-US .
<http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/oPbZa6d9xntUXB><http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/ITEM_ID>"DPDFT-60000395" .
```

The file is loaded by:

```
java -cp blazegraph.jar com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader -defaultGraph http://example.org -namespace kb fastload.properti
es ./couchexport.nt
```

Why cannot the date format be attached as it is possible by blazegraph user interface:
http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/#update

Comment: maybe it doesn't work because of a missing prefix declaration of `xsd:`? What happens if you use the full URI for the datatypes?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Adding the prefix declaration does not help, I already tried that. How would the expression looks like using the full URI for the data type? Could you provide an example, than I can try it again, just for clarificaton. Thanks! –

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the turtle format (*.ttl) again and it worked. I guess the format *.nl needs another format in this matter?!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use prefixes like `xsd:`, `rdfs:`, etc. in a n-triples (*.nt) file. You must use the explicit full-length IRIs even for those datatype annotations. E.g.:

```
<http://example.org/resource1>
  <http://example.org/hasDate>
    "2024-02-23"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> .

<http://example.org/resource1>
  <http://example.org/property1>
    "123"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .
```

However, you can use prefixes in turtle (*.ttl) files, also some of the values don't even need explicit datatype annotations. That's why it worked.

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ex:resource1 ex:hasDate "2024-02-23"^^xsd:date .
ex:resource1 ex:property1 123 .
```